# Does the following algorithm for finding distinct strings work?

Tags: string, algorithm

I recently found a question that went something like:

```
"Given an array of strings, return the number of distinct strings in that array."
```

I came up with this solution:

```
1. Get number_of_strings, which equals the number of strings in the input array
2. Get number_of_non_redundant, which equals the length of the input array cast as a set
3. Return 2 times number_of_non_redundant - number_of_strings
```

So, my question is, does this algorithm work for all data sets?

Comment: where did the 2 times non_redundant - num_strings come from? Wouldn't just the length of the set work?

Comment: isn't that `number_of_non_redundant` is already the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, simply returning `number_of_non_redundant` seems like the answer to this problem.

Here is a possible solution for determining `number_of_non_redundant`:

> 1) Create a Hash Set (Language specific)
>
> 2) Iterate through the entire array, on each element of the array
>   check to see if the element exists in the Hash Set, if it doesn't, add
>   it.
>
> 3) Return the size of the Hash Set.

Using a Hash Set here offers constant time operations(add, contains).

Additionally I wanted to point out that you can't (at least I am not aware of this in a language) simply *cast* an array to a set. *Casting* is a constant time operation. These are two different data structures and in order to take elements from an array and place them in a set, it would require iterating through the array and entering the elements into a set.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the array of strings `["a", "a", "a", "d", "d", "d"]`.

`number_of_strings` is 6; `number_of_non_redundant` is 2. You propose to return `2 * 2 - 6 = -2`. So...no, your algorithm doesn't work for all datasets.

Unless I'm greatly misunderstanding the problem, though, just returning `number_of_non_redundant` will always work, since it's the definition of what you want to return. :)

Comment: Thank you, this was a very solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about first sorting the array lexicographically and then loop over it with a flag variable keeping track of changes between element i-th and (i-1)-th?

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm **DOES NOT** work for all data sets. It might work for specific examples though.

```
say n = number of non redundant strings 
p = number of strings in original array
```

According to you `2n-p = n => n= p`

Your algorithm works only when the `(number of non redundant strings = length of original array)` , which means only when the original array is a set.

Just to give a hint, the ideal way to solve this is hashing if you have enough memory available or you can do it in place using Sorting but would take longer compared to hashing